# Animate <hr> tag on page load

Tags: jquery-animate, animate.css

Hi I'm trying to animate an hr tag on page load like on this link. Is it possible to do without using svg animation? CSS, jquery?

http://themes.opendept.net/photochrom/

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This can be done quite easily with css transitions.

First, give all the hr tags a class, such as "trans--grow"

I usually like to keep transitions in a file named "transition.css" -- or something similar. You don't have to do that however, you can include this in your main css file:

```
.trans--grow{
    -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-out; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 1s  ease-out;
    width : 0%;
}
```

and then add another class in the css. we'll call it grow:

```
.grow{
    width:100%;
}
```

Fun fact: setting the left or right margins of the hr tag to zero will make the hr grow from the left or right, respectively

---

Now, we'll use a little javascript. I'm going to use jQuery, because it seems you asked for it, but you by no means have to use it. Depending on how / when you want to trigger the transition, your code may end up looking different. But let's assume that upon page load will suffice. Your code will look something like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.trans--grow').addClass('grow');
}, 275);
```

And there you have it!

Here's a small example:

http://codepen.io/gasolinewaltz/details/qEZpQa

Comment: It works great. 
Thank you